# Why is this cin reading jammed?

Tags: c++, cin

I've singled out a failure on my program that prevents me from assigning a value to the variable `addAntonymAnswer1`. I've tried running `cin.clear()` before the statement to get the thing read my `yes/no` answer, but the code just won't respond.

The program bit that's failing is located inside `void dictionaryMenu(vector <WordInfo> &wordInfoVector)` and reads

```
         cin.clear();

         cout<<">";
         cin>>addAntonymAnswer1;

         // cin reading STUCK, why!?
```

to get to that point of the program the user has to choose to add a word, and then add a synonym.

The input for running the program is:

```
dictionary.txt
1 cute
2 hello
3 ugly
4 easy
5 difficult
6 tired
7 beautiful
synonyms
1 7
7 1
3 2
antonyms
1 3
3 1 7
4 5
5 4
7 3
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;



class WordInfo{

      public:

             WordInfo(){}

             WordInfo(string newWord){
                           word=newWord;                
             }

             ~WordInfo() { }

             int id() const {return myId;}

             void readWords(istream &in)
             {
               in>>myId>>word;     
             }

             vector <int> & getSynonyms () {

                    return mySynonyms;
             }

            vector <int> & getAntonyms() {

                     return myAntonyms;
            }

            string getWord() {
                     return word;
                   }


          void dictionaryMenu (vector <WordInfo> &wordInfoVector){

          cout<<endl<<"Would you like to add a word?"<<endl;   
          cout<<"(yes/no)"<<endl;
          cout<<">";
          string addWordAnswer;
          cin>>addWordAnswer;

          if (addWordAnswer=="yes")
          // case if the guy wants to add a word
          {
          cout<<endl;                  
          cout<<"Please, write the word "<<endl;                  

          string newWord;
          cout<<">";
          cin>>newWord;
          cout<<endl;         

          WordInfo newWordInfo (newWord);

          int newWordId = wordInfoVector.size() +1;

          newWordInfo.myId=newWordId;

          cout<<"The id of "<<newWordInfo.word<<" is "<<newWordInfo.myId<<endl<<endl; 

          wordInfoVector.push_back(newWordInfo);


          cout<<"Would you like to define which words on the existing dictionary are" <<endl 
          <<"synonyms of "<<newWordInfo.word<<"?"<<endl;


          cout<<"(yes/no)"<<endl;

          string addSynonymAnswer, addAntonymAnswer1, addAntonymAnswer2;
          cout<<">";
          cin>>addSynonymAnswer;  




          if (addSynonymAnswer=="yes")
          {

            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"Please write on a single line the ids for the synonyms of "
            <<newWordInfo.word<<endl<<"starting with its id, which is "<<newWordInfo.myId<<endl<<endl;

            cout<<"For example, to define that the synonym of the word 'cute', which has an id 1, is" 
            <<"'beautiful', which has an id 7, you should write: 1 7"<<endl<<endl;

            cout<<"In the case of "<<newWordInfo.word<<" you should start with "<<newWordInfo.myId<<endl;

            cin.clear();
            string lineOfSyns;
            cout<<">";

            cin>>lineOfSyns;

            newWordInfo.pushSynonyms(lineOfSyns, wordInfoVector); 

            cin.clear();     


                 cout<<"Would you like to define which words on the existing dictionary are" <<endl 
                 <<"antonyms of "<<newWordInfo.word<<"?"<<endl; 

                  //##HERE THE CIN READING OF addAntonymAnswer1 FAILS, WHY?

                 cin.clear();
                 cout<<">";
                 cin>>addAntonymAnswer1;

                 // cin reading STUCK, why!?   


                 if (addAntonymAnswer1=="yes"){ }                        

                    else if (addAntonymAnswer1=="no"){
                         // END DICTIONARY MENU
                         }                  
          }
             else if (addSynonymAnswer=="no"){

                cout<<"Would you like to define which words on the existing dictionary are" <<endl 
                 <<"antonyms of "<<newWordInfo.word<<"?"<<endl; 


                 cout<<">";
                 cin>>addAntonymAnswer2;

                 if (addAntonymAnswer2=="yes"){ }                        

                    else if (addAntonymAnswer2=="no"){
                         // END DICTIONARY MENU
                         }  

             }


          } // if addWordAnswer == "no"

          else if (addWordAnswer=="no"){

               // ######RETURN TO MAIN MENU############
               }        






            }

             void pushSynonyms (string synline, vector<WordInfo> &wordInfoVector){


             stringstream synstream(synline);

             vector<int> synsAux;

             // synsAux tiene la línea de sinónimos

             int num;

             while (synstream >> num) {synsAux.push_back(num);}

             int wordInfoVectorIndex;

             int synsAuxCopyIndex;



             if (synsAux.size()>=2){ // takes away the runtime Error



             for (wordInfoVectorIndex=0; wordInfoVectorIndex <wordInfoVector.size(); wordInfoVectorIndex++)
             {


                 if (synsAux[0]==wordInfoVector[wordInfoVectorIndex].id()){


                    // this is the line that's generating a Runtime Error, Why?                                                       
                    for (synsAuxCopyIndex=1; synsAuxCopyIndex<synsAux.size(); synsAuxCopyIndex++){

                    // won't run yet    
                    wordInfoVector[wordInfoVectorIndex].mySynonyms.push_back(synsAux[synsAuxCopyIndex]);      
                        }                                                          
                 }     
             } 

             }// end if size()>=2


            } // end pushSynonyms








             void pushAntonyms (string antline, vector <WordInfo> &wordInfoVector)
             {



             stringstream antstream(antline);

             vector<int> antsAux;

             int num;

             while (antstream >> num) antsAux.push_back(num);


             int wordInfoVectorIndex;

             int antsAuxCopyIndex;   



             if (antsAux.size()>=2){ // takes away the runtime Error             

             for (wordInfoVectorIndex=0; wordInfoVectorIndex <wordInfoVector.size(); wordInfoVectorIndex++)
             {


                 if (antsAux[0]==wordInfoVector[wordInfoVectorIndex].id()){


                    // this is the line that's generating a Runtime Error, Why?                                                       
                    for (antsAuxCopyIndex=1; antsAuxCopyIndex<antsAux.size(); antsAuxCopyIndex++){

                    // won't run yet    
                    wordInfoVector[wordInfoVectorIndex].myAntonyms.push_back(antsAux[antsAuxCopyIndex]);      
                        }                                                          
                 }     
             } 

             }// end if size()>=2





             }

             //--dictionary output function

             void printWords (ostream &out)
             {
                out<<myId<< " "<<word;     
             }



             //--equals operator for String
             bool operator == (const string &aString)const
             {
                           return word ==aString; 

             }


             //--less than operator

             bool operator <(const WordInfo &otherWordInfo) const
             { return word<otherWordInfo.word;}

             //--more than operator

             bool operator > (const WordInfo &otherWordInfo)const
             {return word>otherWordInfo.word;}

             public: 

                  vector<int> mySynonyms;
                  vector <int> myAntonyms;


                   string word;
                   int myId;


      };

      //--Definition of input operator for WordInfo
      istream & operator >>(istream &in, WordInfo &word)
      {
         word.readWords(in); 

      }



      //--Definition of output operator

      ostream & operator <<(ostream &out, WordInfo &word)
      {
            word.printWords(out);  

      }





      int main() {

          string wordFile;
          cout<<"enter name of dictionary file: "<<endl;
          getline (cin,wordFile);

          ifstream inStream (wordFile.data());

          if(!inStream.is_open())
          {
          cerr<<"cannot open "<<wordFile<<endl; 
          exit(1);                      

          }

          vector <WordInfo> wordInfoVector; 

          WordInfo aword;





          while (inStream >>aword && (!(aword=="synonyms")))
          {
              wordInfoVector.push_back(aword);


          }

          inStream.clear();









          vector <int> intVector;
          string synLine; 






          while (getline(inStream, synLine)&&(synLine!=("antonyms"))){

                aword.pushSynonyms(synLine, wordInfoVector);

                }



          int theIndex;



          string antLine;

          while (getline(inStream,antLine)){

                aword.pushAntonyms(antLine, wordInfoVector);
                }      



          cout<<endl<<"the words on the dictionary are: "<<endl;

          int h=0;          
          while (h<wordInfoVector.size()){
                cout<<wordInfoVector[h]<<endl;
                h++;
                }

          aword.dictionaryMenu(wordInfoVector);

          system("PAUSE");

          return 0;
      }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`cin.clear()` doesn't clear the standard input. What it does is clearing error bits, like `eofbit`, `failbit` and others, and sets the stream into a good state. Maybe you expected it to clear out anything in it? If the user typed

```
yes no
```

Just before, and you

```
cin >> someStringVariable;
```

It will read up to `no` and the stream will still contain

```
 no
```

The call to `clear` then clears any error bits being active. Then, your

```
cin>>addAntonymAnswer1;
```

Will read the `no` that wasn't eaten by the previous read, and the action immediately returns, not waiting for new input. What you should do is doing a `clear` followed by an ignore, up to the next newline. You tell it the amount of characters it should ignore maximally. That amount should be the highest number possible:

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Doing that will make the stream empty, and a following read will wait for you to type something in.

---

Another problem arises if you have got a `cin >>` followed by a `getline`: The cin will leave any whitespace (also newlines) after its read token, but `getline` will stop reading after it hits such a newline. I see you have put `clear` after nearly everything. So i want to show you when you need it and when not. You don't need it when you sequence multiple `cin >>`. Assume you have in your buffer: "foo\nbar\n". Then you do the following reads

```
cin >> a; // 1
cin >> b; // 2
```

After the first, your buffer will contain "\nbar\n". That is, the newline is still in. The second `cin>>` will first skip all whitespace and newlines, so that it can cope with `\n` being at the front of `bar`. Now, you can also sequence multiple `getline` calls:

```
getline(cin, a);
getline(cin, b);
```

Getline will throw away the `\n` that it reads at the line end, but won't ignore newlines or whitespace at the begin. So, after the first getline, the buffer contains "bar\n". The second getline will correctly read "bar\n" too. Now, let's consider the case where you need the clear/ignore:

```
cin >> a;
getline(cin, b);
```

The first will leave the stream as "\nbar\n". The getline then will see immediately the `\n` at the begin, and will think it read an empty line. Thus, it will immediately continue and not wait for anything, leaving the stream as "bar\n". So, if you have a `getline` after a `cin>>` you should first execute the clear/ignore sequence, to clear out the newline. But between `getline` or `cin>>`'s, you should not do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is "stuck" because it is waiting for input. cin is attached to the standard input handle for the program, you have to type something and hit enter.

Comment: I mean "stuck"in the sense that it doesn't let me "type something and hit enter". The console inmediately presents "Press any key to continue".

Comment: i don't think he deserves a downvote. "getting stuck" means it doesn't continue, which i think he correctly interpreted. instead, maybe change the wording in your question.

Comment: it assumes the poster doesn't know that "cin s attached to the standard input handle for the program, you have to type something and hit enter", which I find borderline offensive, the guy didn't even read my code.

Comment: I read your code. My answer seemed the most likely based on what I could see. You should explain your problem a little better

Answer (score 1):

`cin >> ...` reads from standard input until it finds a whitespace character.  When you enter, say, `8 5` for the list of synonyms, `8` gets read into `lineOfSyns` and nothing more.  When the program reaches `cin >> addAntonymAnswer1`, `5` gets read into `addAntonymsAnswer1`.  Your program behaves unexpectedly since it expects `yes` or `no` but it got `5`.

Look at using `cin.getline()` instead of `>>`.  See, for example, sections 18.2 and 18.3 of  [this page](http://www.tenouk.com/Module18.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'm using getline now due to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In your program you ask the user:

```
Please write on a single line the ids for the synonyms of test
starting with its id, which is 8

For example, to define that the synonym of the word 'cute', which has an id 1, i
s'beautiful', which has an id 7, you should write: 1 7

In the case of test you should start with 8
```

Then you attempt to read in the line the user typed with

```
cin>>lineOfSyns;
```

However, this only reads up to the first whitespace.  So the 2nd number typed in by the user is still in the `cin` buffer when the

```
cin>>addAntonymAnswer1;
```

line is executed, so that data gets read into the `addAntonymAnswer1` string.  The user never gets an opportunity to type in 'yes' or 'no' and your tests for those values fail.

You should consider changing to using the `string` overload for `getline()` to do your reads:

```
getline( cin, stringvar);
```

This would probably be better than using `cin.getline()`, as that does not have an overload that takes `string` - with that member function, you need to read into an array of chars, which is far less flexible than reading into a `string`.

Comment: You should consider changing to using the `string` overload for getline() to do your reads:  getline( cin, stringvar);