# Using `getline(cin, s);` after using `cin >> n;`

Tags: c++, stream

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;

std::string s = "";
std::getline(cin, s);
```

I noticed that if I use `cin`, my program would hang the next time I reach the line `getline(cin, rangeInput)`.

Since `getline()` is using `cin`, is that why it is causing the program to hang if I have previously used `cin`? What should I do if I want to get a line after using  `cin`?

Comment: It works for me with the input 1 2 3. whatv input is it failing with for you?

Comment: Try just entering one digit and pressing enter (to get someNum). Anyways, I'm reading the link posted William. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear the input stream - try adding the following after your cin:

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

The accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478258/why-is-this-cin-reading-jammed) question gives a good explanation of why/when this is required.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin` leaves an extraneous `\n` in the input stream. When you use `std::getline()`, you are retrieving that `\n`.

Although @WilliamLannen's answer works if you *really* need `std::cin`, you are better off using this method:

```
int n;
std::string sn;
std::stringstream ssn;

std::getline(std::cin, sn);
ssn << sn;
ssn >> n;
```

---

> ### References
>
> http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/tutorials/71858

Answer (score 0):

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;


std::cin.get() //<--- use cin.get() here ...


std::string s = "";
std::getline(cin, s);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations.