# Clear cin in C++

Tags: c++, cin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is this cin reading jammed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478258/why-is-this-cin-reading-jammed)

I overloaded the istream operator (`istream &operator>>...`) and it takes in a Point of the format:

```
(<x-coordinate>,<y-coordinate>)
```

I want to test this out multiple (10) times, and so have written:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  {
    cin >> a;
    if (!cin.fail()) { cout << a << endl; }
    else { cout << "Invalid input!" << endl; cin.clear(); }
}
```

EDIT:

I now have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  {
    cin >> a;
    if (!cin.fail()) { cout << a << endl; }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid input!" << endl; cin.clear();
        while (!cin.eof()) { cin.ignore(); } cin.ignore();
    }
}
```

The ignore was suggested by Cthulhu. However, the problem is cin still outputs "Invalid input!" after running through the code above:

```
(3,3) <-- input
(3,3) <-- output
Invalid output! <-- second output
```

Is there a way that I can clear what is in cin?

Comment: `cin.clear()` clears the flags, not the contents. You want `ignore`.

Comment: Sadly, "jammed" is not a term I would have searched for and tl;dr. :)

Comment: `tl;dr` isn't good reply to helpful answer.

Comment: @Supervisor: If the prior material on the topic is too long for you to bother reading, then your question is too long for me to bother answering.

Comment: Sorry Ben. No disrespect. :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin.clear()` does not empty the buffer, it resets error flags on the stream.
You then have to call **[cin.ignore](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore/)**

```
istream&  ignore ( streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF );
```

> Extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them.
>
> The extraction ends when n characters have been extracted and
>   discarded or when the character delim is found, whichever comes first.
>   In the latter case, the delim character itself is also extracted.

---

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

**[Numeric Limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)**

Comment: I replaced cin.clear() with cin.ignore() and got the same results.

Comment: You need both. Also call `cin.clear` with the right arguments. A number of buffer characters to be cleared, and a delimiter, at which clearing stops.

Comment: Even with:

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

It still has one output of "Invalid inptut!"

I will just use a boolean to keep track of whether or not it went into the else statement and skip the "\n" manually. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The output is the same still?

Comment: It's:

(3,3)
(3,3)
Invalid input!