# My program input wouldn't save into a text file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi every one i wrote the code below it is of a diary project it is still in the early stages so when you run it its suppose to tell you to enter a diary entry and then save it in a text but it is not being saved in file please help!!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
 ofstream wysla;
wysla.open("wysla.txt, ios::app");
int kaput;
string s1,s2;
cout<<"Please select from the List below"<<endl;
cout<<"1.New entry"<<endl;
cout<<"2.View Previous Entries"<<endl;
cout<<"3.Delete an entry"<<endl;
cin>>kaput;
switch (kaput)
{
case 1:

    cout<<"Dear diary,"<<endl;
    cin>>s1;
    wysla<<s1;
    wysla.close();

    break;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a typo here

```
wysla.open("wysla.txt", ios::app);
```

Comment: in the same program when i enter a long string it only picks the first word.. when i try using getline the string isn,t saved in the text file what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to Daniel A. White's answer you will probably run into the problem, that only one word is saved in your file.
This is caused by this line:

```
cin>>s1;
```

You should rather use

```
getline(cin, s1);
```

here.

Comment: a  did that but now it wunt even save a single word!! what myt be the solution

Comment: This is most likely due to the cin>>kaput leaving a '\n' character behind in the input-buffer. This will lead to getline(cin, s1) returning an empty string (since it only reads to the next '\n'). See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478258/why-is-this-cin-reading-jammed) on how to flush the input-buffer.