# using cin to close a while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm trying to verify my user input using a while loop. Please see below for my code/while loop. I want them to enter a float number, and I'm trying to verify that they have entered a number rather then a letter/sentence. I think this loop should work but when I run it if I enter a number it craps out before reaching the end of the program and if I enter a string it touches the `cout` statement, fails to ask for the `cin`, and then validates the loop.  If you could explain what and why is happening as well as how to fix it I would really appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>   
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float mph, i = 0;
    cout << "this program will calculate the distance a train will travel in a given amount of time." << endl;
    cout << "What is the speed of the vehicle in mph? ";
    cin >> mph;
    cout << endl;


    while (mph > -3.4E-38 && mph < 3.4E38);
    {
        cout << "that is not a number, do not pass go, do not collect $200 but DO try again." << endl;
        cin >> mph;
        // trace statement to check whats happening in the loop
        cout << "trace: " << mph << "faluer: " << i << endl;
        i++;
    }
    cout << "works twice" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Raphael, i guess i kind of under stand what  you mean (i'm new to C++) but maybe i asked the wrong question.  What i'm trying to do is validate user input, in the simplest way possible.  i'm asking the user to supply numbers and i want to use a while statement to check that he has entered a number, doesn't matter if it's an integer or a float, so long as it's not string or a char.  what is the best way to do this using a while statement?  i thought my while statement  did that, but maybe it's not the best way to go about it? what is the best way to validate user input for a number?

Comment: if you're referring to the answer Raphael posted, then that is exactly what it does, and he explains how it works also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your code inside the while loop to something like:

```
cout<<"that is not a number, do not pass go, do not collect $200 but DO try again."<<endl;

if (!cin) { // we enter the if statement if cin is in a "bad" state.
    cin.clear(); // first we clear the error flag here
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // now we skip the input,
                                                                   // that led to the invalid state
}

cin>>mph;
```

if you enter a string and try to read it into a `float` with `cin`, `cin` goes into invalid state and refuses to read any input until cleared.
That's what my suggested code above tries to fix. Note that you got to include `<limits>` for it to work.

Related link for more information on clearing the input stream: [Why is this cin reading jammed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/478258/1942027)