# why cin.get only wait for user input once

Tags: c++

I am expecting the following program to stop twice for waiting my input characters. The first time it stops and wait me to type a character, I typed a character and press enter, however the console doesn't wait me to input 'char c' after that, it just end and prints out only what I typed for 'char b'. Why is that?

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        char b;
        cin.get(b);
        char c;
        cin.get(c);
        cout << b << c << endl;
    }
```

Comment: It is accepting 'enter' as the second character.

Comment: Whether you know it or not, you entered more than one character. Count how many times you hit a key on your keyboard; don't leave *anything* out.

Comment: Not really a dupe, but you should read the first answer.  You need to ignore the carriage return.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478258/why-is-this-cin-reading-jammed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question states:

1) Some key on the keyboard was pressed.

2) Another key on the keyboard labeled "Enter" was pressed.

Pop quiz: how many characters were typed?

Answer: two characters were typed.

The first `get()` reads the first character. The second `get()` reads the second character, the `Enter` key.(*)

(*) The above answer assumes a non-multibyte locale.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
char b;
cin >> b;
char c;
cin >> c;
cout << b << c << endl;
```