# Reading in a new line after cin>> doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11, io

I have problems processing a newline read from stdin:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
...

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ...

    unsigned int maxelems;

    cout << "Maximal number of elems that can be taken in one move: ";

    if (!(cin >> maxelems)) {

        cout << "Bye!" << endl;
        return 1;
  }

  string pl1_str;

  cin.ignore();

  cout << "Player 1 (hu=human, ra=random, opt=optimal):" << endl;

  if (!(getline(cin, pl1_str))) {

      cout << "Bye1!" << endl; return 1;

  }

  if(pl1_str =="hu")
        //do smth
    else if(pl1_str =="ra")
        //do smth
    else if(pl1_str=="opt")
       //do smth
    else {
        cout << pl1_str << "Bye2!" << endl; return 1;
    }

    ...
}
```

When I run this, the cin on maxelems and the flushing with cin.ignore() works.

When I get to:

```
Player 1 (hu=human, ra=random, opt=optimal):
```

and I enter:

```
hu<Enter>
```

The end of line seems not to be reached. When I press Enter again:

```
hu<Enter><Enter>
```

the application ends with "Bye1!" which is not what I want.

Now if I insert another cin.ignore():

```
...
cout << "Player 1 (hu=human, ra=random, opt=optimal):" << endl;
cin.ignore();
...
```

and I enter:

```
hu<Enter>
```

the line is processed, but the application terminates with:

```
u Bye2!
```

Ok, cin.ignore() cuts of the "h" , but why is the line suddenly processed? How can I assign "hu" to pl1_str?

**Edit:**

I solved this. Actually there wasn't a problem :-).

After

```
...
  if(pl1_str =="hu")
    //do smth
else if(pl1_str =="ra")
    //do smth
else if(pl1_str=="opt")
   //do smth
else {
    cout << pl1_str << "Bye2!" << endl; return 1;
}

...
```

I had another getline() in the code, which was checking the same conditions:

```
string pl2_str;

if (!(getline(cin, pl2_str))) {

      cout << "Bye2!" << endl; return 1;

  }

//Here I forgot to insert:  cout << "Player 2 (hu=human, ra=random, opt=optimal):" << endl;

if(pl2_str =="hu")
    //do smth
else if(pl2_str =="ra")
    //do smth
else if(pl2_str=="opt")
   //do smth
else {
    cout << pl2_str << "Bye2!" << endl; return 1;
}
```

So of course if I enter:

```
hu<Enter><Enter>
```

an empty string is parsed via the second getline() and the code returns. If I couted "Bye3" I would have noticed that earlier.

Comment: `exit 1` shouldn't even compile. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also have a read of the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478258/why-is-this-cin-reading-jammed).

Comment: I made ... after my last #include statement, so if you add #include <unistd.h>, it compiles fime. It nevertheless wouldn't compile because of the ... I inserted three times. But ok, if I that makes you happy, I changed exit 1 to return 1