# Exception doesn't continue loop correctly

Tags: c++, oop

I'm currently learning about exceptions, so this might seem trivial but I'm learning.
So, a user is asked if he wants to enter an integer or a string, if he selects an integer and types a string anyway, I want an error to occur.

Here is part of the code I'm working on:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MyList
{
protected:
    T* elems;
    int itsSize;
public:
    MyList(int itsSize):itsSize(itsSize)
    {
        elems = new T[itsSize];
    }

    ~MyList()
    {
        delete [] elems;
    }

    int getSize()
    {
        return itsSize;
    }

    virtual void addElem(){}
};

template <class T>
class MyStack : public MyList<T>
{
public:
    MyStack(int size):MyList<T>::MyList(size){}

    void addElem(int i)
    {
        cin >> MyList<T>::elems[i];
        if(cin.fail())
            throw "Wrong String Input--> will enter 0";
    }
};



int main()
{
    int numItems;
    try
    {
      cout << "How many items to store?" << endl;
      cin >> numItems;
      if(numItems<0)
        throw "Invalid Number.";
    }
    catch(const char* negativeValue)
    {
        cout << negativeValue << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int storeChoice;
    cout << "Would you like to store integers or strings (1,2)?" << endl;
    cin >> storeChoice;

    if(storeChoice==1)
    {
        MyStack<int> numList(numItems);

        for(int i=0; i<numItems; i++)
        {
          try
          {
            cout << "Enter num:";
            numList.addElem(i);
          }
            catch(const char* wrongInput)
            {
               cout << wrongInput << endl;
            }
        }
    }
     else if(storeChoice==2)
    {
        MyStack<string> stringList(numItems);

        for(int i=0; i<numItems; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter string:";
            stringList.addElem(i);
        }

}
};
```

The thing is, if I type a string, the loop continues but doesn't let me type the next input
Here is [my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiFv4.png) and this is the [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sPwb.png). I also want to set it to zero instead if a string is entered.

Comment: Please add the error and the expected result as plain text, instead of as links or images.

Comment: This is **not** due to the exception! After reading an unexpected non-integer the stream remains in error state. You need to `clear()` it and discard the invalid input by `ignore()`ing it. There are duplicates here on SO somewhere, looking for one.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478258/why-is-this-cin-reading-jammed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad input sets the `failbit` but doesn't throw exception by default.

you might use [basic_ios::exceptions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) to have exception:

```
std::cin.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);
int numItems;

try
{
    std::cout << "How many items to store?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> numItems;
    if(numItems<0)
        throw "Invalid Number.";
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::cerr << "'" << line << "' is not a number\n";
    // ...
}
catch (const char* negativeValue)
{
    std::cout << negativeValue << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I think their problem wasn't that it wasn't throwing exceptions more that after a failure, reading from `cin` doesn't work anymore

Comment: First catch clause seems to suggest that OP terminates the program whether such error happens.

Comment: Added error handling.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you! May I ask what string line& get line do exactly? I know it stores the input and prints it. However, I was tinkering around and the code wouldn't work unless I had these two lines (I changed it to cerr; when I removed those two lines)

Comment: input "buffer" has still invalid data for number, so you have to consume them. `std::getline` or `cin.ignore(..)` might do that.